# Sharing Spark SQL tables between applications

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In driver program I used Spark SQL to save some data extracted from Twitter stream  in table. I'm not using Hive, so it was saved to `spark-warehouse` directory. Then I tried accessing it through `spark-shell`, but the table wasn't available by `sql()` command (it wasn't even listed in `sqlContext.tables`). Tables created both by drive program and spark-shell are persisted in the same folder, but are invisible to application they don't originate from.

Should Spark behave that way? Am I missing something?  Is there a way to share these tables?

---

Update: I managed to piece together an example. I submitted driver with following code:

```scala
  Seq(1).toDF("number").write.saveAsTable("number")
  spark.sqlContext.sql("select * from number").show
```

And the result is:

```
  +------+
  |number|
  +------+
  |     1|
  +------+
```

Then I run following command in `spark-shell`:

```scala
scala> sql("select * from number")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: number; line 1 pos 14
```

---

Update 2. I managed to create the workaround by appending even empty `DataFrame` to table, so I can access it normally.

```scala
scala> spark.sqlContext.emptyDataFrame.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable("number")
scala> sql("select * from number")
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [number: int]

scala> sql("select * from number").show
+------+
|number|
+------+
|     1|
+------+
```

But now driver program can't access table by Spark SQL. It seems that table is  available only to application, that has most recently written to it. Is there any way to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the table via `df.createOrReplaceTempView("number")` on the second application:

```
// App1
val df = Seq(1).toDF("number")
df.write.saveAsTable(hdfsOrS3Path)
```

Read back in the second app:

```
// App2: 
val df = spark.read.parquet(hdfsOrS3Path)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("number")
spark.sqlContext.sql("select * from number").show
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Save the desired dataframe through spark application

```
//I am saving a dataframe in parquet format to hive tables
dfTest.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("myDB.number")
```

Step 2: Access them in spark shell

```
var readDF = sqlContext.read.parquet("/user/hive/warehouse/myDB.db/number")
or
var readDF = sqlContext.sql("select * from myDB.number")
```